# How do I verify my URL for Slack apps using Render?

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, hosting, slack

I'm trying to deploy my slack bot on Render, but I need to verify my Request URL per Slack's documentation to use /slash commands (see image below). I've read Slack's documentation, but I still have no clue how I'm supposed to implement a response with a `challenge` value to the POST request. Is that a feature that's supposed to be available via my hosting provider, or am I suppose to use express in my code to handle a POST request to the route that I'm actively hosting on?

As in, I'm hosting my code on a onrender.com url; my code also contains a route handler for that onrender.com url; and when I verify the url via Slack, it's going to POST to the onrender.com url and my code is going to execute on that POST request given the route handler is within the code, thus verifying my Request URL.

This is my first time deploying any type of code, so it's been a bit difficult to wrap my head around this - please let me know if any of this was confusing or if I should rephrase my question.

**Slack image**

[image]

**Code**

```
// Configurations for Bolt, Dotenv, and PG-Promise
const { App } = require("@slack/bolt");
require("dotenv").config();
const pgp = require("pg-promise")();


// Establishes connection to database
const conn = {
  host: [hostname],
  port: 5432,
  database: "lookerbot",
  user: "lookerbot_user",
  password: process.env.DB_CONNECT_KEY,
};

const db = pgp(conn);

// Initializes slack app with bot token and signing secret
const app = new App({
  token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_KEY,
  signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SECRET_KEY,
  appToken: process.env.SLACK_APP_KEY,
});

// SLACK APPLICATION CODE

// Command gb-help returns a welcoming message with a list of all available commands
app.command("/gb-help", async ({ command, ack, respond }) => {
  // Acknowledge command request
  await ack();

  // Sends block with help information back to user
  await respond({
    blocks: [
      {
        type: "header",
        text: {
          type: "plain_text",
          text: "Welcome to GlossaryBot :wave:",
          emoji: true,
        },
      },
      {
        type: "section",
        text: {
          type: "mrkdwn",
          text: "To make your life easier, I'm a glossary for all of our company's metrics :tada:. Need my help? Simply type */gb* for GlossaryBot and see where that takes you! ",
        },
      },
      {
        type: "section",
        text: {
          type: "mrkdwn",
          text: "Unfortunately I'm not a chatbot :robot_face:, so please see below for a complete list of available commands:",
        },
      },
      {
        type: "section",
        text: {
          type: "mrkdwn",
          text: "• */gb-help* - lists all available commands \n • */gb-list* - lists all words in glosssary \n • */gb-define [word]* - defines word in glossary \n • */gb-add* - add word to glossary \n • */gb-remove [word]* - remove word from glossary",
        },
      },
      {
        type: "divider",
      },
      {
        type: "context",
        elements: [
          {
            type: "plain_text",
            text: "Developed by Julian Ordaz :face_with_cowboy_hat:",
            emoji: true,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  });
});

...

(async () => {
  // Start your app
  await app.start(process.env.PORT || 3000);

  console.log("⚡️ Bolt app is running!");
})();
```